# How to change Font size in Application Insights Dashboard

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler, azure-dashboard

I have a query in Application Insights which returns Text and Percentage Values.

But its not in enough size , How can we increase Font Size ?
In the below Picture the font size of the percentage value is not as required, How can we increase Font Size ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The font size isn't configurable in this Blade. Feel free to use the browser zoom though.